# What does <- mean in scala with yield?

Tags: scala, operators

I'm pretty new to Scala and came up with the following construction:

```
val value=
  for {
    p1 <- getList()
    p2 <- parser.parse(p1)  //parser.parse(String) Returns some useful value
  } yield p2
value.asJava
```

Where

```
def getList(): List[String] = {
   //compiled code
}
```

I don't quite understand what's going on in the first piece of code. Searching for ***scala left arrow operator*** did't shed the light on this. Can't you explain it?

Comment: See http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html

Comment: I guess I really don't understand why someone would start to learn scala and not have a (online or ebook or dead-tree) tutorial to hand. Every one of those would explain `for... yield`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for {
    p1 <- getList()
    p2 <- parser.parse(p1)
  } yield p2
```

is equivalent to (psudocode, not tested):

```
var result: List = Nil
val value = {
    foreach(p1 in getList()){
     foreach(p2 in parser.parse(p1)){
      result ::: p2
     }
    }
    result
   }
```

But like others said, you could have easily found this by reading up on Scala's `for` comprehension.

Comment: That is a lot of psuedocode for something which is essentially just `getList().flatMap(parser.parse)`.

Comment: I know @Peter. I was attempting to demonstrate it in an OO way.